# C# - Deserialize Json object having Multiple Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am receiving this string Json format from API.

```
string rawJson = "[{\"RequestID\":12345,\"Status\":100,\"ResponseMessage\": \"API Call Successful\",\"ResponseData\":[{\"EmployeeID\":\"1824\",\"MatchedDateTime\":[\"20 Oct 2020 06:41:45 AM\"]},{\"EmployeeID\":\"1214\",\"MatchedDateTime\":[\"20 Oct 2020 06:05:03 AM\"]}]}]"
```

[image]

I wanted the ReponseData in a List so i did the below.

```
 public class TO_JsonLogs
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("ResponseData")]
        public Dictionary<string, TO_JsonPunches> TO_JsonPunch { get; set; }
             
    }

    public class TO_JsonPunches
    {
        public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string MatchedDateTime { get; set; } 
    }

var logsJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TO_JsonLogs>(rawJson);
```

It gives the below error on this line.

> Error converting value `"[{"RequestID":12345,"Status":100,"ResponseMessage": "API Call Successful","ResponseData":[{"EmployeeID":"1824","MatchedDateTime":["20 Oct 2020 06:41:45 AM"]},{"EmployeeID":"1214","MatchedDateTime":["20 Oct 2020 06:05:03 AM"]}]}]"` to type 'TO_JsonLogs'. Path '', line 1, position 256.

Any idea how to get this data in list.

Comment: Perhaps this can help to see what is going wrong: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationTracing.htm
Also when I throw this json into a json2csharp to create a model, it is showing a list<string> MatchedDateTime. https://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deserialize it in this way

```
    public class Request
    {
        public string RequestID;
        public int Status;
        public string ResponseMessage;

        public List<ResponseDataItem> ResponseData;
    }

    public class ResponseDataItem
    {
        public string EmployeeID;
        public List<string> MatchedDateTime;
    }

    var logsJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Request>>(rawJson);
```